# Pandas getting unique index after concatenating list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem:** I have the following pandas dataframe object which was initially concatenated based on a dataframes list (in which each dataframe `df_*` carries `check_*` information). Below dataframe is only an example, the real one carries more (stage, unit) combinations (and I don't know a-priori how many).

**Aim**: Stage and unit shall be the index which carry the values for `check_*`. So essentially, for each stage, unit combination I want to have one unique row carrying the information for `check_*`.

Any idea how to do that? Many thanks!

```
# Current Situation
stage   unit    check_1 check_2 check_3 check_4
A       min     NaN     NaN    120      NaN
B       min     NaN     NaN    210      NaN
A       sec     NaN     NaN    3        NaN
B       sec     NaN     NaN    3        NaN
B       min     NaN     NaN    NaN      0.8
A       min     NaN     NaN    NaN      0.3


# Target
stage   unit    check_1 check_2 check_3 check_4
A       min     NaN     NaN    120      0.3
B       min     NaN     NaN    210      0.8
A       sec     NaN     NaN    3        NaN
B       sec     NaN     NaN    3        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.groupby` and `sum`:

```
check_cols = df.filter(like='check_', axis=1).columns.tolist()
res = df.fillna(0).groupby(['stage', 'unit'])[check_cols].sum()
```

Comment: @rkraft Please let me know if the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = df.groupby(['stage', 'unit'], as_index=False).first()
```